# The Like button does not change to Dislike, Django

Tags: python, django

When a user puts a Like, the reverse Dislike button should be displayed, but this does not happen. If you remove the if condition, then like and dislike work separately, the data is written to the database and deleted accordingly. But there is a problem with the if condition. When the user has already put a Like, the information is not taken from the database that they need to put a Dislike instead of a Like. Do not understand why.

models.py:

```
class PostLike(models.Model):
    userlikepost = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    likepost = models.ForeignKey(Userpublication, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('userlikepost', 'likepost')
```

views.py:

```
def show_post(request, post_slug):
    post = get_object_or_404(Userpublication, slug=post_slug)
    like_count = PostLike.objects.filter(likepost=post).count()

    liked_by_current_user = False
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        liked_by_current_user = PostLike.objects.filter(likepost=post, userlikepost=request.user).exists()

    print(f'liked_by_current_user: {liked_by_current_user}') 

    context = {
        'post': post,
        'like_count': like_count,
        'liked_by_current_user': liked_by_current_user,
    }
    return render(request, 'pie/home.html', context)

@login_required
def like_post(request, post_id):
    try:
        post = Userpublication.objects.get(pk=post_id)
        like, created = PostLike.objects.get_or_create(userlikepost=request.user, likepost=post)
        like_count = PostLike.objects.filter(likepost=post).count()

        like_count = PostLike.objects.filter(likepost=post).aggregate(count=Count('id'))['count']

        return JsonResponse({'liked': created, 'like_count': like_count})
    except Exception as e:
        return JsonResponse({'error': str(e)}, status=500)

@login_required
def unlike_post(request, post_id):
    try:
        post = Userpublication.objects.get(pk=post_id)
        like = PostLike.objects.filter(userlikepost=request.user, likepost=post).first()
        if like:
            like.delete()
        like_count = PostLike.objects.filter(likepost=post).count()
        return JsonResponse({'unliked': True, 'like_count': like_count})
    except Exception as e:
        return JsonResponse({'error': str(e)}, status=500)
```

html:

```
{% if post.liked_by_current_user %}
    <div class="unlike-button" data-post-id="{{ post.id }}">Dislike<span class="like-count-value" data-post-id="{{ post.id }}">{{ like_count }}</span></div>
{% else %}
    <div class="like-button" data-post-id="{{ post.id }}">Like<span class="like-count-value" data-post-id="{{ post.id }}">{{ like_count }}</span></div>
{% endif %}
```

JS:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        function updateLikeCount(postId, likeCount) {
            $('#like-count-' + postId + ' .like-count-value').text(likeCount);
            
        }

        $('.like-button').click(function() {
            var postId = $(this).data('post-id');
            var csrfToken = '{{ csrf_token }}';
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRFToken': csrfToken
                },
                url: '/like/' + postId + '/',
                success: function(data) {
                    if (data.liked) {
                        updateLikeCount(postId, data.like_count);
                    }
                },
                error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                    console.error(xhr.responseText);
                }
            });
        });

        $('.unlike-button').click(function() {
            var postId = $(this).data('post-id');
            var csrfToken = '{{ csrf_token }}';
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRFToken': csrfToken
                },
                url: '/unlike/' + postId + '/',
                success: function(data) {
                    if (data.unliked) {
                        updateLikeCount(postId, data.like_count);
                    }
                },
                error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                    console.error(xhr.responseText);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>


<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    function updateLikeCount() {
        $('.like-count-value').each(function() {
            var postId = $(this).data('post-id');
            var likeCountElement = $(this);
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '/get_like_count/' + postId + '/',
                success: function(data) {
                    var likeCount = parseInt(data.like_count);
                    if (!isNaN(likeCount)) {
                        likeCountElement.text(likeCount);
                        
                    }
                },
                error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                    console.error(xhr.responseText);
                }
            });
        });
    }

    
    updateLikeCount();

    $('.like-button').click(function() {
        var postId = $(this).data('post-id');
        var csrfToken = '{{ csrf_token }}';
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'X-CSRFToken': csrfToken
            },
            url: '/like/' + postId + '/',
            success: function(data) {
                if (data.liked) {
                    updateLikeCount(); 
                }
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                console.error(xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
    });

    $('.unlike-button').click(function() {
        var postId = $(this).data('post-id');
        var csrfToken = '{{ csrf_token }}';
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'X-CSRFToken': csrfToken
            },
            url: '/unlike/' + postId + '/',
            success: function(data) {
                if (data.unliked) {
                    updateLikeCount(); 
                }
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                console.error(xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of points

1. Your context variable should be referred to as

```
    {% if liked_by_current_user %}
```

as it is a separate context variable, not a method or attribute of post.

2. Your If statement is in your template. It won't change unless the page is reloaded and the template recalculated. However, because you are using ajax to submit your like/dislikes, the page doesn't reload and so the template doesn't deliver new HTML.

The easiest way to fix this is to add code to change your button to your ajax success method. So to change Like to Dislike, something like...

```
//find the button
buttonToChange = document.querySelector("[data-post-id='" + postID + "']")
//toggle the button class
buttonToChange.classList.add('unlike-button')
buttonToChange.classList.toggle('like-button')
//change the button text
buttonToChange.textContent = ButtonToChange.textContent.replace("Like", "Dislike")
```